# Windows Batch Script parsing multiline file with variable line formats?

Tags: windows, parsing, for-loop, scripting

I need to parse a file that has the following format:

```
A + tags/RWSTestConsole_tag1/
           (from trunk/RWSTestConsole/:r776)
```

So I'm using a FOR /F loop with a counter and inspecting the tokens based on whether I'm looking at line 1 or line 2. Everything works fine except the first token for line 2 includes the leading spaces ("    from") and a) I thought the delims on my FOR would take care of spaces and b) theoretically I could just compare to a constant string that is set to "    from" but that's kind of hokey.

This is my FOR command:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=():/ " %%a in (svn.txt) DO (
```

Is there a change I can make to the FOR command to ignore the spaces? If not is there a way to trim the token inside the FOR loop's DO clause so I only get the word without the leading spaces?

Edit:

This is output from a Subversion SVNLOOK command in a script that is managing whether or not to allow a "tag" to be created. The output can be 1 line that must be formatted as:

D   /tags/*tagfoldername*/

If it's one line but it's not a delete for the actual tag folder then it's an error. This case is handled.

If it's more than 2 lines it's a list of files and that's an error. I have that handled.

The case I'm having problems with is if it is 2 lines it needs to be in the format shown above:

A + tags/RWSTestConsole_tag1/
    (from trunk/RWSTestConsole/:r776)

Where col 1 = "A". col 3 = "+", col 5 = "tags" and the remainder of line one is the tag folder name. The second line is the source of the create request so it has to start with "from", followed by "trunk", "branches" or "tags" followed by a single-level folder name and a revision number.

I used the FOR command as described above. In the DO clause I look at a counter to tell if I'm parsing line 1 or line 2. Line 1 is simple, I have all the logic to handle it.

Line 2 is parsed by the same FOR command and the first token (%%a) removes the "{" from delims, but leaves behind all the leading blanks so I get back %%a="     from".

I need to know if there's a way I can modify the FOR command to remove the blanks or a way to trim %%a within the FOR DO clause to remove the blanks.

Edit 2: FOR Loop Code

```
set c=1
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=():/ " %%a in (svn.txt) DO (
echo op=%%a, %%b, %%c, %%d, %%e
if !c!==1 (
    set rc1=0
    if /I %%a EQU A (
        if "%%b" EQU "+" (
            if  [%%e] EQU [] (
                echo Tag from a Copy Op
                set rc1=0
            ) else (
                echo Found a subfolder: %%e - not a tag delete
                set rc1=1
            )
        ) else (
            echo Tag not a Copy 
            set rc1=1
        )
    )
)
if !c!==2 (
    set rc2=0
    set str1=%%a
    echo String replace 1 = !str!
    set str2=!str1:~-4!
    echo String Replace 2  *!str2!*
    if /I !str2! EQU FROM (
        set isvalid=false
        if %%b EQU trunk set isvalid=true
        if %%b EQU branches set isvalid=true
        if %%b EQU tags set isvalid=true
        if !isvalid! EQU true (
            set rc2=0
        ) else (
            set rc2=1
            echo Invalid source for Tag Creation
        )
    ) else (
        set rc2=1
        echo Tag not FROM
    )
)
set /a c+=1
)

echo RC1=!rc1!
echo RC2=!rc2!
set /a rc=!rc1!+!rc2!
echo final RC = !rc!
```

Comment: Hokey resolution: I used SET with substrings to extract the right-most 4 characters from the string to get the "FROM". If it's not "FROM" then I have an error which is what I want, but it seems hokey. A more elegant solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Explain how you need to parse the file and provide a sample to download.  There are tools and different methods depending on what the output needs to look like.

Comment: See edits above with more info on the file. There's no point in actually providing a file since it always only has 2 lines in the format above.

Comment: The resulting line looks to be exactly the same as the 2 lines joined, but with only one space from the start of line 2.  Is that right? `A + tags/RWSTestConsole_tag1/ (from trunk/RWSTestConsole/:r776)`  Or do you need a different output?  The actual output will dictate which way to handle the file.

Comment: Theoretically they could be joined but the raw output of the command can be 1, 2 or many lines so I'd only want to join them if it was 2 lines of output. I guess I could modify my code to save line 1 and join it to line 2 then parse line 2 but that seems excessive. I'm parsing both lines exactly as I need them with the exception of the leading blanks in the first token of line 2 (the "    from").

Comment: We can't see your files or your code.  How can we give advice with actual details about the task?  To remove leading spaces from a line you can use `for /f "delims=*" %%a in ("  (from") do echo "%%a"`

Comment: People seem to frown on posting large blocks of code. I can post all the code but much of it is directly related to getting information from Subversion. If it will help I can post the entire FOR loop including the DO clause. The file being processed is exactly as described. We have a very closed network and I can't access any file upload sites due to our Internet policies. I provided as much information as I can about the file.   I tried the for command as for /f "delims=*" %%A in (
"%%a") do set str=%%A to strip the leading blanks but when I echoed !str! it still had the leading blanks.

Comment: Posted testing code for FOR loop processing of 2-line file.

Comment: You'd need to post enough code to reproduce the problem. Will it do that?  `isvalie=true` <--- and you have a typo here.   `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (" (from") do echo "%%a"` <-- And my example was wrong, sorry - try this

Comment: Typo corrected. Thanks. The code posted will reproduce the problem. Copy the code into a BAT file and copy the two lines starting with "A + " into a file "SVN.txt" in the same directory. You have to add some leading blanks in front of the "(from" - SO is stripping them and won't let me add them. Run the BAT file and you should see an ECHO of the strings with the "FROM" in it. I tried FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in ("%%a") DO set str=%%A to strip the blanks but when I ECHO !str! after the FOR the blanks are still there. This would be in the code where the "ECHO String replace..." statements are...

Comment: I tried your code before I replied - it doesn't show anything that explains the problem to me.  You can try my code above at the cmd prompt to prove it works.  Wrap the variable in quotes to echo it, to illustrate spaces.  Does your file have TAB characters in it?

Comment: The sample code uses set with a ~4 to get the "FROM" from the right end of the string so the ECHO statements show a valid string. Anyhoo, we had a long discussion on this particular use case and decided we don't need to parse the "FROM" line at all so this issue is moot. Thanks for all your help. Sorry for the frustration in replicating the problem. I appreciate the time you spent trying to help me out.